# Remove unused X axis levels in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to have the ggplot only display levels where there is data. So for the first facet S7, S8, S9 should not appear & for the second facet  S1, S2, S3 should not appear. Please let me know if I articulated myself correctly.

```
df = data.frame(v1 = c('A','A','A','B','B','B'),
           v2 = c('S1','S2','S3','S7','S8','S9'),
           nm = c(2,3,4,5,6,7))



ggplot(df,aes(x =  v2, y = nm)) +
  geom_point(size = 3) +
  facet_grid(.~v1)
```

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ggplot: how to remove unused factor levels from a facet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57026999/ggplot-how-to-remove-unused-factor-levels-from-a-facet)

Answer (score 7):

Use `scales = "free_x"` to control whether the x-axis is forced to have the same limits on different facets:

```r
library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(
  v1 = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B"),
  v2 = c("S1", "S2", "S3", "S7", "S8", "S9"),
  nm = c(2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)
)



ggplot(df, aes(x = v2, y = nm)) +
  geom_point(size = 3) +
  facet_grid(. ~ v1, scales = "free_x")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-01-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you sooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo much